# how to configure a service for unit testing in angular

Tags: angular, jasmine

One of the service(ProductService) is dependent on the LoggerService, want to perform the unit testing ofProductService.
Spyobj Loggerservice is registered in the provider of the testbed and in the testcase will get the ProductService using TestBed.Inject(ProductService).

Compared testcase with the one of the example available in the angular.io -> https://angular.io/guide/testing-services
In the example both Service and dependent service are registered in the provider of the testbed.

Do we need to register in the provider array of the test bed before getting the ProductService using TestBed.Inject?

```
            let masterService: MasterService;
            let valueServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ValueService>;

            beforeEach(() => {
              const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ValueService', ['getValue']);

              TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                // Provide both the service-to-test and its (spy) dependency
                providers: [
                  MasterService,
                  { provide: ValueService, useValue: spy }
                ]
              });
              // Inject both the service-to-test and its (spy) dependency
              masterService = TestBed.inject(MasterService);
              valueServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(ValueService) as jasmine.SpyObj<ValueService>;
            });


            export class LogserviceService {

              constructor() { }

              public logMessage(value:string)
              {
                console.log(value);
              }
            }

            export class ProductService {

               products:IProduct[]=[];

              constructor(private logservice:LogserviceService) {
                console.log('getting the service created');
                console.log(logservice);
                console.log(logservice instanceof (LogserviceService));
               }
              getProducts(): IProduct[] {

                this.products =
                [
                  {name:"TV",cost:100,model:"123434",category:"Electronics"},
                 
                ];

                this.logservice.logMessage("I am in the product service");

                return this.products;
              }

              getProduct(category:string):IProduct[]
              {
                this.logservice.logMessage("callling getProduct");

                let products = this.getProducts();
                let prodct= products.filter(x=>x.category ===category);
                return prodct;
              }

            }

            describe('ProductService', () => {
              let service: ProductService;
              let logService: LogserviceService;

              logService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['logMessage']);
              beforeEach(() => {
                TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                  providers: [{ provide: LogserviceService, useValue: logService },
                    
                  ],
                });
              });

             
              it('should get the product list, if valid caterogy is sent', () => {
               
                let service = TestBed.inject(ProductService);  //product service not registered in the providers
                let products = service.getProduct('Electronics');

                expect(products.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
                expect(logService.logMessage).toHaveBeenCalledWith('callling getProduct');
                expect(products[0].category).toEqual('Electronics');

              });
            });
```

Comment: Well, why do you write : `//product service not registered in the providers` when few line above there is actually the very `ProductService` in the providers array ?

Comment: I have deleted the productservice from the shared snippet. Do we need to register the service before accessing it

Comment: From what I experienced, you don't, and it's not injected when you call `ng generate service` as well ... so this would need some clarification.